# Why? PHP Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, image

I do not understand because it gives this error I'm paying the parameters but still generates the error me here this class and use it as the line that gives me the error is 108

```
imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $value, $value_versus, $this->width, $this->height);
```

Here is the class

```
<?php class thumb {

var $image;
var $type;
var $width;
var $height;

//---Método de leer la imagen
function loadImage($name) {

    //---Tomar las dimensiones de la imagen
    $info = getimagesize($name);

    $this->width = $info[0];
    $this->height = $info[1];
    $this->type = $info[2];

    //---Dependiendo del tipo de imagen crear una nueva imagen
    switch($this->type){
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
           ##Creamos la marca de agua =)
            $imagen1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
            $imagen2 = imagecreatefromjpeg( "img/loguito.jpg" );
            $imagen3 = imagecreatefrompng( "img/water.png" );
            $x = intval( imagesx( $imagen1 ) - imagesx( $imagen2 ) ) / 1.02;
            $y = intval( imagesy( $imagen1 ) - imagesy( $imagen2 ) ) / 1.02;

            $x2 = intval( imagesx( $imagen1 ) - imagesx( $imagen3 ) ) / 1.02;
            $y2 = intval( imagesy( $imagen1 ) - imagesy( $imagen3 ) ) / 1.02;

            $x3 = intval( imagesx( $imagen1 ) - imagesx( $imagen3 ) ) / 10.02;
            $y3 = intval( imagesy( $imagen1 ) - imagesy( $imagen3 ) ) / 10.02;
            imagecopy( $imagen1, $imagen2, $x, $y, 0, 0, 80, 68 );
            imagecopy( $imagen1, $imagen3, $x2, $y2, 0, 0, 400, 150 );
            imagecopy( $imagen1, $imagen3, $x3, $y3, 0, 0, 400, 150 );

            ///imagejpeg( $imagen1, 'fotos/ttt'.basename($name) );
            $this->image = imagejpeg($imagen1);
            //$this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($name);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($name);
            break;
    }
}

//---Método de guardar la imagen
function save($name, $quality = 100) {

    //---Guardar la imagen en el tipo de archivo correcto
    switch($this->type){
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            imagejpeg($this->image, $name, $quality);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif($this->image, $name);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $pngquality = floor(($quality - 10) / 10);
            imagepng($this->image, $name, $pngquality);
            break;
    }
    imagedestroy($this->image);
}

//---Método de mostrar la imagen sin salvarla
function show() {

    //---Mostrar la imagen dependiendo del tipo de archivo
    switch($this->type){
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            imagejpeg($this->image);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif($this->image);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            imagepng($this->image);
            break;
    }
    imagedestroy($this->image);
}

//---Método de redimensionar la imagen sin deformarla
function resize($value, $prop){

    //---Determinar la propiedad a redimensionar y la propiedad opuesta
    $prop_value = ($prop == 'width') ? $this->width : $this->height;
    $prop_versus = ($prop == 'width') ? $this->height : $this->width;

    //---Determinar el valor opuesto a la propiedad a redimensionar
    $pcent = $value / $prop_value;
    $value_versus = $prop_versus * $pcent;

    //---Crear la imagen dependiendo de la propiedad a variar
    $image = ($prop == 'width') ? imagecreatetruecolor($value, $value_versus) : imagecreatetruecolor($value_versus, $value);

    //---Hacer una copia de la imagen dependiendo de la propiedad a variar
    switch($prop){

        case 'width':
            imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $value, $value_versus, $this->width, $this->height);
            break;

        case 'height':
            imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $value_versus, $value, $this->width, $this->height);
            break;

    }

    //---Actualizar la imagen y sus dimensiones
    //$info = getimagesize($name);

    $this->width = imagesx($image);
    $this->height = imagesy($image);
    $this->image = $image;

}

//---Método de extraer una sección de la imagen sin deformarla
function crop($cwidth, $cheight, $pos = 'center') {

    //---Hallar los valores a redimensionar
    $new_w = $cwidth;
    $new_h = ($cwidth / $this->width) * $this->height;

    //---Si la altura es menor recalcular por la altura
    if($new_h < $cheight){

        $new_h = $cheight;
        $new_w = ($cheight / $this->height) * $this->width;

    }

    $this->resize($new_w, 'width');

    //---Crear la imagen tomando la porción del centro de la imagen redimensionada con las dimensiones deseadas
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($cwidth, $cheight);

    switch($pos){

        case 'center':
            imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, abs(($this->width - $cwidth) / 2), abs(($this->height - $cheight) / 2), $cwidth, $cheight, $cwidth, $cheight);
            break;

        case 'left':
            imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, abs(($this->height - $cheight) / 2), $cwidth, $cheight, $cwidth, $cheight);
            break;

        case 'right':
            imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, $this->width - $cwidth, abs(($this->height - $cheight) / 2), $cwidth, $cheight, $cwidth, $cheight);
            break;

        case 'top':
            imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, abs(($this->width - $cwidth) / 2), 0, $cwidth, $cheight, $cwidth, $cheight);
            break;

        case 'bottom':
            imagecopyresampled($image, $this->image, 0, 0, abs(($this->width - $cwidth) / 2), $this->height - $cheight, $cwidth, $cheight, $cwidth, $cheight);
            break;

    }

    $this->image = $image;
}}?>
```

And this is how i use

```
$mythumb = new thumb();$mythumb->loadImage($path);$mythumb->resize($ancho, 'width');$mythumb->show();
```

Comment: The faulty part is in the `loadImage` function. You're assigning the return value of `imagejpeg` to `this->image` - which means the variable is either `true` or `false`. You probably meant to assign `$imagen1` to `$this->image`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how could solve the problem I can not use the function imagecreatefromjpeg

Comment: You don't need to, you already created a GD object, now you only need to save that object in `$this->image`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! solved `$this->image = $imagen1` and erase `$this->image = imagejpeg($imagen1);`